# SecureSocial for Play 2.3.8

Tags: scala, playframework, securesocial

I restored a project I dint open for a while, it is based on Play Framework 2.3.8 for Scala 10.0.4.
Right after the first compilation attempt, activator started upgrading Play to 2.4.2, and it seems to be related with SecureSocial master-SNAPSHOT dependency. Checking an ivy local cache backup, I found the `ivy-master-SNAPSHOT.xml` of `securesocial_2.10` folder had a different `info` than the one activator is downloading now. The old version had the following info:

```
    <info organisation="ws.securesocial"
    module="securesocial_2.10"
    revision="master-SNAPSHOT"
    status="integration"
    publication="20150201200657"
    >
```

and of course pointed to the proper play version:
`<dependency org="com.typesafe.play" name="play_2.10" rev="2.3.7" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>`

activator is being force to download 2.4.2 dependencies and causing the expected compilation nightmare, since the new `ivy-master-SNAPSHOT.xml` has referencies like: `<dependency org="com.typesafe.play" name="play-server_2.10" rev="2.4.2" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>`
With the following info:

```
<info organisation="ws.securesocial"
        module="securesocial_2.10"
        revision="master-SNAPSHOT"
        status="integration"
        publication="20151215111200"
>
```

So the question is, how can I make the old project run properly with Play 2.3.8 and SecureSocial, by (I'm guessing) adjusting `build.sbt`?

Comment: I looked into SecureSocial source and I found at least one version compatible with Play 2.3.x: `3.0-M3`